# Product Statistic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report

I do the statistic function for my project. I have the order table with some fields as:

- `prouct_id`,
- `amount`,
- `order_date`.

The customer ask me to do the auto scale statistic as: I get the `MIN(order_date)` of a `produc_id` and the current date to calculate **the days**:

- If **the days** about ~ 1 month ==> show the statistic of the product by weeks
- If **the days** about ~ 1 year  ==> show the statistic of the product by months
- If **the days** >= 2 year ==> show the statistic of the product by year

I hope that can receive the ideas, examples from all of you about making the statistic as above.

Comment: Your question appears to be lacking a question.

Comment: What do you mean by select product by weeks, by months and by year do you mean `GROUP BY` week, `GROUP BY` month, ..? And What RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You didn't specify what RDBMS is this. So let me assume that it is SQL Server, and you can do this:</strike>

```
;WITH MinDates AS
(
    SELECT 
      produc_id,
      MIN(order_date) order_date
    FROM products
    GROUP BY produc_id
), DatesWithIntervals AS
(
    SELECT 
      product_id,
      order_date,
      CASE 
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 31      THEN 1
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 365     THEN 2
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 365 * 2 THEN 3 
        ELSE 4
      END "Interval"
    FROM MinDates
)
SELECT
  product_id,
  order_date
  ...
FROM DatesWithIntervals 
--Do your statics here
```

You didn't specify what statistics do you want to compute. But you should be able to do whatever statistics you want to do using the last cte: `DatesWithIntervals` depending on the field `Interval` and I will leave it as a practice for you.

**Edit:** For MySQL, just replace all these `CTE`s with subqueries like so:

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  order_date
      ...
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      product_id,
      order_date,
      CASE 
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 31      THEN 1
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 365     THEN 2
        WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(dd, order_date, GETDATE())) < 365 * 2 THEN 3 
        ELSE 4
      END "Interval"
    FROM
    (
         SELECT 
          produc_id,
          MIN(order_date) order_date
         FROM products
         GROUP BY produc_id  
    ) MinDates
) DatesWithIntervals 
--Do your statics here
```

Comment: @user1826306 - OK, I updated my answer. But you didn't tell what statistics you want to do on the final table?

Comment: The statistic give the report week/month/year for a specific product. Ex: Prouct A, the min date for selling date is 25 October 2012, so the report will base on "week"